# Business Intelligence in SharePoint - which technology for my task?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, business-intelligence

I have some stuff to do in SharePoint for my departure, but i am really overhelmed by the features and i don't get a right overview what i can do with which feature (e.g. Excel Services, Performance Point, Dashboard, Chart Controls, ...).

My first problem: I should make some kind of customer satisfaction monitoring. E.g. after each project with the customer, he should fill out some interview about his satisfaction with the results. Then there should be a graphic in sharepoint which monitors the increase or decrease of customer satisfaction. How could i do a table (or list) which should hold scores (from 1-5) for each question and calculate a average score for each date when the customer filled out a interview form.

I am a real beginner with sharepoint. I am reading some books at the moment (but some of them for sharepoint 2007 and we are using sharepoint 2010). I tried to google it but i could not find a real clear answere or howto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you said you are a beginner.I will vote for an Excel Dashboard ( Web Based ).
You can pull the data in excel and draw a chart ( may be bar graph over months ) and then put this excel in SP document library to render a Web Excel based dashboard.

Easiest and scalable.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a SharePoint survey. You can set up the questions in the manner you described and I believe there's a "overview" view that displays the results graphically. You could also display the graphics using something like the Bamboo Poll web part (http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-poll-web-part.aspx).

Here's some info on creating a survey: http://blog.fpweb.net/creating-adding-to-and-modifying-a-sharepoint-survey/

Here's another good article on creating simple web parts to display your results:
https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/create-a-polling-web-part-with-sharepoint-designer-and-the-dvwp.aspx